# File format for storing text as easily accessible lines

Tags: file-io, data-structures, file-format

I have a data structure (B-Tree) that stores text as a series of nodes each one representing a single line of the text. I would like to store the text in a file that I could keep in sync with the structure without having to rewrite the entire file on each edit. So when line n of my structure is changed I can access and change only line n of the file keeping it updated with the structure.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

The reason for this is I'm trying to store the state of my structure so I can restore after a crash, but without the overhead of constantly writing the entire file. (Could be a lot of data)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

If you go this route, keep in mind all relational databases are built on B-Trees. So you may consider using some embedded database, like SQLite, instead.

Comment: The data structure I'm using to store the text is a B-Tree. My question is how to store that structure in a file in a way that is easily updated.

Comment: That's why I suggested using SQLite - it does serialize the B-Tree to disk for you. If you can't use an existing database engine, you can just serialize your B-Tree as continuous collection of `[line-id, flags, size, data]` tuples. When a line changes, you set the `deleted` flag in an existing tuple, and write a new tuple at the end of the file. The B-Tree in memory holds offset to the latest tuple on disk. From time to time (daily?) compact the file by removing the deleted tuples and updating the B-Tree in memory.